# Linux Symlink command between two directories adds a directory to link path

Tags: command, symlink, laravel-envoy

so I have a server with Linux to which I deploy staging Laravel application from Gitlab using the Gitlab Envoy guide

The structure of folders is as follows:

- /public_html/ `main folder where user is redirected to`
- /releases/ `folder with all releases`

  - /timestampA/ `specific release app`
  - /timestampB/ `specific release app`

There is a problem when creating a symlink between

```
ln -nfs releases/timestamp public_html
```

the symlink that is created looks like this

> ./releases/timestamp -> public_html/timestamp

now it is supposed to be like this

> ./releases/timestamp -> public_html

does anyone know why this happens and possibly how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `public_html` already exists and is a directory.

From the `man ln` (bold is mine):

> Given one or two arguments, `ln` creates a link to an existing file
> `source_file`.  If `target_file` is given, the link has that name;
> **`target_file` may also be a directory in which to place the link**;
> otherwise it is placed in the current directory.  If only the directory is specified, the link will be made to the last component of `source_file`.

In order to achieve what you want you should remove the `public_html` folder first (or add `-F` option to `ln` command, but it's not guaranteed to work).

Comment: Okay and in that case, say I need to have laravel .env in public_html file or storage directory, which should contain the current application enviromental variables and storage data.
I would be unable to make a symlink there since public_html would not be a directory, or am I incorrect?